# Values of helper collection_select is being called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model Category:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects
end
```

Model project:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  validates :title, :description, :category, :skill, :payment, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: { only_integer: true }

  PRICE_CATEGORIES = ['cat_price1', 'cat_price2', 'cat_price3', 'cat_price4']

end
```

projects/new

```
<%= form_for @project, url: {action: 'create'} do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label 'Titel' %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<P>
  <%= f.label 'Budget' %>
  <%= f.text_field :price %>

  für

  <%= f.select :price_category, Project::PRICE_CATEGORIES %>
</P>
<p>
  <%= f.label 'Beschreibung' %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label 'Kategorie' %>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
</p>

<P>
  <%= f.submit 'erstellen' %>    
</P>

<% end %>
```

schema.rb:

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.string   "skill"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "payment"
    t.boolean  "anonymity"
    t.string   "file"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.string   "price_category"
  end
```

When calling  **<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>**

all items in dropdown list displaying twice. Cant undestand, why. 
For example:

- cat1
- cat2
- cat3
- cat1
- cat2
- cat3

Thank for you help.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have duplicate entries in your database?

Comment: yes, i check with rails c - Category.all

Comment: What does console return on 
`helper.collection_select :project, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name` ?